# How do I pass command line arguments to stack exec

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm building a Haskell program that uses a command line argument parser using option-applicative library. Since I'm using stack to build and test my project, I would like to execute my program passing command line arguments using stack exec, like

```
stack exec myprogram-exe -i myfile.txt
```

but when I try to execute, Stack gives me the following message:

```
Usage: stack exec CMD [-- ARGS (e.g. stack ghc -- X.hs -o x)] ([--plain] |
              ([--ghc-package-path] | [--no-ghc-package-path])
              ([--stack-exe] | [--no-stack-exe]) [--package ARG])
```

Is there a way in which I can pass command line arguments to a program executed using Stack?

Comment: Try this `stack exec -- myprogram-exe -i myfile.txt` ?

Comment: @sibi that's the correct approach. Can you write it in as an answer? `$(stack exec which foo)`  would also work on Unix shells

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
stack exec -- myprogram-exe -i myfile.txt
```

Another way as Michael Snoyman says should be like this:

```
$(stack exec which foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `stack build` with the `--exec` flag to build and execute in one command. The arguments to the executable have to be included in the exec argument.

```
$ stack build --exec "myexecutable arg1 arg2"
```